# Use node.js and ANSIcolor plugin in Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, chalk

I want to display colored output in jenkins which is produced by node.js

Both work separately, but not combined:

Node Script
My test script test.js:

```
console.log(require("chalk").red("Node Red"))
```

Calling the test script in the **shell** works:

```
node test.js => OK
```

Calling a colored shell script in **jenkins** works:

```
echo -e "\033[31mShell Red\033[0m" => OK
```

But calling the node script in **jenkins** does not display any colors:

```
node test.js => No Color, when executed in jenkins
```

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked when putting

```sh
export FORCE_COLOR=1
```

at the top of my script.

See https://github.com/chalk/supports-color#info

Answer (score 3):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57679967/655051) of [Raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11940/raphael-schweikert) pointed me in the right direction. Here my complete solution for a Jenkins Pipeline Script (Scripted Pipeline):
:

```
node {
    ansiColor('xterm') {
        withEnv(['FORCE_COLOR=3']) {
            ...
            sh "some-node-script-using-chalk.js"
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using the Declarative Pipeline see https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/ how to set environment variables in a Declarative Pipeline Script.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the problem in my case :

- In The Job Configuration
- Look at the Bindings
- Check the checkbox named "Color ANSI Console Output"

And it works (for  me...)